# Multipass fails to launch an instance on OSX BigSur 11.7

Tags: macos, unix

After installing Multipass using `brew install multipass` or directly from the Canonical website, a persistent error occurs when starting an instance:

```
multipass shell
start failed: The following errors occurred:                                    
Instance stopped while starting
```

OS signature is `Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 29 04:31:06 PDT 2022; root:xnu-7195.141.39~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Inspecting the logs at `/Library/Logs/Multipass/multipassd.log` I found some errors I cannot understand:

```
[2023-05-22T16:27:27.687] [debug] [update] Latest Multipass release available is version 1.11.1
[2023-05-22T16:27:28.972] [warning] [daemon] Ignoring ghost instance in database: rapid-lionfish
[2023-05-22T16:27:28.972] [warning] [daemon] Ignoring ghost instance in database: successful-snake
[2023-05-22T16:27:28.975] [info] [rpc] gRPC listening on unix:/var/run/multipass_socket
[2023-05-22T16:27:28.976] [info] [daemon] Starting Multipass 1.11.1+mac
[2023-05-22T16:27:28.976] [info] [daemon] Daemon arguments: /Library/Application Support/com.canonical.multipass/bin/multipassd --verbosity debug
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.741] [debug] [primary] Waiting for SSH to be up
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.741] [debug] [primary] process working dir ''
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.742] [info] [primary] process program '/Library/Application Support/com.canonical.multipass/bin/hyperkit'
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.742] [info] [primary] process arguments '-c, 1, -m, 1024M, -u, -A, -H, -U, 386bba5a-5dc4-3ac2-95c9-cf0b9a29b352, -s, 0:0,hostbridge, -s, 2:0,virtio-net, -s, 5,virtio-rnd, -s, 31,lpc, -l, com1,autopty=/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/pty,log=/Library/Logs/Multipass/primary-hyperkit.log, -s, 1:0,virtio-blk,file:///var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img?sync=os&buffered=1,format=qcow,qcow-config=discard=true;compact_after_unmaps=262144;keep_erased=262144;runtime_asserts=false, -s, 1:1,ahci-cd,/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/cloud-init-config.iso, -f, kexec,/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-generic,/var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-initrd-generic,earlyprintk=serial console=ttyS0 root=/dev/vda1 rw panic=1 no_timer_check'
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.742] [info] [primary] process state changed to Starting
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.744] [info] [primary] process state changed to Running
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.749] [error] [primary] Using fd 5 for I/O notifications
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.751] [info] [primary] mirage_block_open: block_config = file:///var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img?sync=os&buffered=1 and qcow_config = discard=true;compact_after_unmaps=262144;keep_erased=262144;runtime_asserts=false and stats_config = None

[2023-05-22T16:27:48.769] [info] [primary] hyperkit: [INFO] Resized file to 24212 clusters (3099136 sectors)
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.769] [info] [primary] hyperkit: [INFO] block recycler starting with keep_erased = 2048
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.769] [info] [primary] hyperkit: [INFO] image has 0 free sectors and 24208 used sectors
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.769] [info] [primary] mirage_block_open: block_config = file:///var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.img?sync=os&buffered=1 and qcow_config = discard=true;compact_after_unmaps=262144;keep_erased=262144;runtime_asserts=false and stats_config = None returning 0
mirage_block_stat

[2023-05-22T16:27:48.769] [info] [primary] /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/cloud-init-config.iso: fcntl(F_PUNCHHOLE) Operation not permitted: block device will not support TRIM/DISCARD
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.910] [error] [primary] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 4 bit: 12 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.910] [error] [primary] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 4 bit: 20 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.910] [error] [primary] vmx_set_ctlreg: cap_field: 3 bit: 13 unspecified don't care: bit is 0
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.910] [info] [primary] linkname /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/pty
COM1 connected to /dev/ttys002

[2023-05-22T16:27:48.910] [error] [primary] kexec: failed to load kernel /var/root/Library/Application Support/multipassd/vault/instances/primary/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-generic
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.911] [error] [primary] process error occurred Crashed
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.911] [info] [primary] process state changed to NotRunning
[2023-05-22T16:27:48.911] [info] [primary] process finished with exit code 6
[2023-05-22T16:33:00.138] [debug] [primary] Waiting for SSH to be up
```

Any Idea of what's going on?

Comment: It tells you at the bottom of the log; look for the ones marked “error”.  In this case, a particular kext failed to load:  `ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-vmlinuz-generic`.  I’m not familiar with multipass, but this library looks suspect.  I’d start with this error when doing research.

Comment: Thank you. I've finally has been told the most recent update of multipass for macOS has broken Hyperkit. There is a work-around using qemu instead: `multipass set local.driver=qemu`. See https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/3087

Comment: Post that as an answer and ping me here (@Allan).  I’ll send an up vote your way!

Comment: done @Allan. Thank you

Comment: Covered!  Hopefully they’ll get it sorted quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally has been told the most recent update of multipass for macOS has broken Hyperkit. There is a work-around using qemu instead:

```
multipass set local.driver=qemu
```

This is only true for intel-based macs. The multipass version for ARM-based macs is yet using qemu.

See this support bug report answered by Chris Townsend:
https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/3087